# Front end = ..nginux.. = Back end?

Tags: node.js, proxy

My question might seem dumb, but im highly uneducated on this topic, but i really want to learn how this is all working.

For the sake of example let me provide you with a scenario.

I have front end built with react, the website has all the required http requests and sends everything that is required to my server. The server is running on nodeJs(express).

The website and a server are working just fine, both of them are on different ports. Front end is on localhost:3000, and back-end is on localhost:8000.

Recently i started spending a considerable amount of time, trying to understand how real applications work and what needed to deploy them. At this moment i came across a few articles that suggest to use a proxy server that can be like a "bridge"(maybe for secuirty reasons (my guess)).

So could somebody give me insights to understand this concept?

Im sorry if the question might seem a bit dumb to you, but its hard to find good information on the inet about it.

If i understand this concept completely wrong and there is nothing in this sort, just comment below and i will delete this thread.

Comment: What is serving your front end on port 3000?

Comment: The setup sounds a bit unusual. Why do you have separate server instance for the frontend?

Comment: Sky=>response=>localmachine on my pc just for testing purposes, react

Comment: JJJ, ok lets say im not using express, but RESTIFY, i dont like using rendering templates in nodejs. Its horrible...

Answer (score 0):

Nginx can work as a reverse proxy, which means it will allow you to access localhost:8000 from http://localhost (port 80).
This is useful, for example, when you have different domains and you want to point domain1.com to localhost:8000 and domain2.com to localhost:9000.

Hope you understand it now. Ask me anything else if you need to.

Comment: yes it does make sense, i watched a few videos on the internet. People are saying it can also increase the speed of http requests if you are running like 3-4 proxy servers

Comment: I don't think so. A proxy by definition can't speed up an HTTP request, only slow it down. A different scenario is if you are serving static pages and you use nginx as web server instead of proxy, nginx may be faster than node when serving those specific static pages. Nginx can be a reverse proxy or a web server, or both at the same time, depending on how you configure it.